# Easy Java Simulations - Exporting to Applet Issue

Tags: swing, deployment

I am using Easy Java Simulations, a tool designed to created simulations. Having designed my simulation when I export it to an Applet to run in the browser, then the JVM loads but hangs. But the same simulation if exported as an executable .jar file, runs perfectly fine. What could be the possible reasons? Also, is there any way I can take the executable .jar and embed it in an HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

> ..is there any way I can take the executable .jar and embed it in an HTML page?

A better alternative is to upload the Jar to the server and launch it free-floating using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: thanks :) I will try that, although I also figured out how to get past the EJS issue.